# помогите с кодом в javascript

Tags: javascript, for

смотрю видеокурс "уроки программирования" от loftblog, тема - циклы. Столкнулся с проблемой - полностью переписываю сам код, как на видео. У них - всё работает, у меня -нет.
вот код:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(i=0; sum=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  sum+=arr[i];
};
  console.log(sum);
```

вот что выдаёт консоль:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.4.min.js:1:13924
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.4.min.js:1:10866"
```

в комментариях к видео ещё несколько человек пишут о том, что у них такой код не работает. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените точку с запятой на запятую:

```
for(i=0, sum=0; i<arr.length; i++)
```

Comment: спасибо! действительно, не заметил, хотя несколько раз смотрел код

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, в цикле забыли `var` в объявлении переменной.

Во-вторых, параметры нужно отделять запятой.

В-третьих, это рекомендация, неправильная работа с областью видимости в коде. `sum` нужно объявлять до цикла.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: спасибо, действительно не внимательно код переписал, а вот объявление переменных было не обязательно, хотя так тоже пробовал, но проблоема была именно в запятых